# How to convert BMPs (bitmap black&white) to 1-bit color depth animated GIF

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, image-conversion, bmp

I have a sequence of BMPs that are 1bpp (1-bit color depth, black & white of course). I want to combine them into a single animated GIF, with 1-bit color depth. Is this possible?

So far I have tried `ffmpeg`, but the output is always 8-bit depth. Using `-pix_fmt monob` doesn't help, it always defaults to `gray` (which is 8-bit depth). I used an online GIF optimizer (ezgif) to (somehow) reduce it to 6-bit depth but never get the 1-bit depth that I wanted.

The reason for this is I want the file size to be as small as possible, using 8-bit for a black & white GIF is a waste I think. In the end, that GIF will be converted to C-array that is stored on a microcontroller.

Comment: Not possible with the FFmpeg GIF encoder. `ffmpeg -h encoder=gif` shows `Supported pixel formats: rgb8 bgr8 rgb4_byte bgr4_byte gray pal8`, none are 1 bit. I did not investigate if GIF supports what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for completeness of the answer:

Not possible with GIF!
GIF supports only Pixel Format Indexed8bpp.
Which is a indexed color palette of 256 colors, you could cut down the palette to two colors, but it still would use 8-bits per index. Added that RLE compression might cut the file size down, but it still wouldn't be 1-bpp.

If you are not looking for just animated image, but rather static image, please read further.

On the other hand BMP, PNG, or TIFF can produce Pixel Format Indexed1bpp, while only PNG and TIFF support Monochrome (BlackWhite) 1-bpp.
You'll need software capable of indexed palette with only two (2) colors, or Monochrome 1-bpp (Black and White). And to map pixels values to those two (2) indexes.
Choose to save BMP, PNG, or TIFF with pixel format indexed 1-bpp; or PNG and TIFF with pixel format monochrome 1-bpp. Adobe Photoshop is capable of this using Mode from Image menu. Windows Imaging Components (WIC) has native support these two pixel formats, so might any image editing software that uses WIC to load and save images.
Otherwise for any in house solutions you'll have to check supported formats for that solution.

Note: each BYTE should have eight (8) pixels when written in BMP, PNG, or TIFF file when pixel format is Monochrome 1-bpp or Indexed 1-bpp.